# Why does Miyuki lose when Miyuki is hardly in the story?

Tags: kaguya-sama-love-is-war

S01E08 story of the last sub-episode - Miyuki (Shirogane) apparently loses according to the narrator. Miyuki is hardly in the story though. Why does Miyuki lose? I guess it's because Kaguya might've been higher in exam results if not for tutoring Yu (Ishigami) ?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is  precisely because he did not appear much.

Based on the manga version, the story ends with Shirogane's narration that he did not play a role in training Ishigami. As Kaicho and a male senpai, he was sort of supposed to take the lead in helping Ishigami, but the role was taken by Kaguya. That seems to be why it is Shirogane's loss.

Comment: But wait, I think you should use spoiler tag/text if you're getting from the manga?